# Trouble counting number of instances in a row

Tags: python, csv

Hello I'm creating a grading system which opens a .csv file and goes down a list of students calculating for each of them how many passes, merits and distinctions they got.

**Sample Data**

```
First Name, Last Name, Test 1, Test 2, Test 3
John,        Doe,        P,       P,       M
Mary,        Jane,       P,       D,       M
Bruce,       Wayne,      P,       M,       D
```

So John will have 2 passes, 1 merit. Mary 1 of each etc.
Here's the code I'm working on.
Unfortunately it is counting the grades vertically so row[1] is 3 passes, row[2] is 1 etc. instead of reading it hortizontally. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import csv
import collections

#Create Counter
grades = collections.Counter()

#Open file and read
with open('Results.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)


    for row in csv_reader:
        grades[row[2]] += 1

        print('Number of Pass grades: %s' % grades['P'])
        print('Number of Merit grades: %s' % grades['M'])
        print('Number of Distinction grades: %s' % grades['D'])
```

Comment: `grades[line[2]]`? this is where you having problem you should check`grades[line[2]]`, `grades[line[3]]` and `grades[line[4]]`

Comment: Yes, when I try row, line or column it goes vertically. Sorry I'm a bit of a python noob.

Comment: other solution is use `csv.DictReader` then you can access the value with column name or simply use other loop `for grade in line[2:]: grades[grade] += 1`

Comment: That's currently adding them all together. I need a for line in csv_reader before your code otherwise it doesn't like the word 'line'

Comment: That is a strange looking CSV file. The first row seems to be using `,` (comma) as the column separator while subsequent rows seem to be using tab characters as the column separator. What is the actual separator?

Comment: Oh sorry it is commas I just forgot to include them there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the passes, merits and distinctions for each row. Then add the number of passes, merits, and distinctions to a list respectively for each record horizontally using `list.count()` method [(details on list.count)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

`input_data.csv`:

```
First Name,Last Name,Test1,Test2,Test3
John,Doe,P,P,M
Mary,Jane,P,D,M
Bruce,Wayne,P,M,D
```

`code.py`:

```
import csv

with open("input_data.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    result = []
    header_column = True
    for data in csv_reader:
        if header_column:
            header_column = False
            continue        
        row = data[:]
        row.append(data[2:].count("P"))
        row.append(data[2:].count("M"))
        row.append(data[2:].count("D"))
        result.append(row)
    print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['John', 'Doe', 'P', 'P', 'M', 2, 1, 0], ['Mary', 'Jane', 'P', 'D', 'M', 1, 1, 1], ['Bruce', 'Wayne', 'P', 'M', 'D', 1, 1, 1]]
```

**Explanation:**

- We skip the first row from the `result` list as it contains the header information.
- The `result` is a 2D list where each inner list contains the following information sequentially: [`First name`, `Last Name`, `Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3`, `Number of passes`, `Number of merits`, `Number of distinctions`]
- Here `data[2:]` ensures that we do not count `P`,`M` or `D` value in `First Name` and `Last Name` column.

**Alternative solution:**

- We can use the `csv.DictReader` that will make each record as a dictionary.

**References:**

- [1: Python documentation on list.count](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: I'll try that! Thank you so much!